# Aliexpress price history dataset

Tags: data-request, api, uses-of-open-data, historical, prices

I want to find any dataset on Aliexpress products' price history? I found only one good quality website - https://www.pricearchive.org/ but according to their faq - they "do not provide special access (including via API) to any data shown on the pages of our website." Aliexpress own API doesn't seem to give access to the price history.

Comment: This website is just a affiliated with Aliexpress. It does not have price history data. Try to search i.e Mobile and from dropdown menu select everywhere and see the result.

Comment: "It has not give any priceing history data"? [See this page](https://www.pricearchive.org/aliexpress.com/item/32799238870) Any product on this website has a chart and a table with price history data. One more example from your suggestion to search for Mobile - [link](https://www.pricearchive.org/aliexpress.com/item/32770581433)

Comment: [sistastore](https://www.sistastore.com) also has AliExpress product's price history.